# JPA-Hibernate : Abstract class collection raises "object references an unsaved transient instance" exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Not duplicate**

To summarize the issue :

I have an `Order` entity which has a list of `Menu` and each `Menu` has a list of `Item` which is an abstract class. See below for details.

Abstract classe :

```
 @Entity
 @Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS )
 public abstract class Item implements Serializable{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,generator = "ItemIDGenerator" )
   @TableGenerator( table = "SEQUENCES", name = "ItemIDGenerator" )
   protected Long id;

  //.....
}
```

And my concrete classes :

```
@Entity
public class ItemA extends Item{
}

@Entity
public class ItemB extends Item{
}

@Entity
public class ItemC extends Item{
}
```

The tables of those concrete entities already exist in database.

Then :

```
@Entity
public class Menu implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private Long          id;

  //one directional relation
  @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = false )
  @JoinTable( name = "menu_item", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "ID_MENU", referencedColumnName = "id" ) }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "ID_ITEM", referencedColumnName = "id" ) } )}
  private List<Item> items;//problem is here 

  //bi-directional
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST )
  @JoinColumn( name = "ID_ORDER", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = false )
  private Order   order;
}
```

Finally :

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long         id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "order", orphanRemoval = true )
    private List<Menu>   menus;
}
```

The problem is when I persit a `Menu` entity I have this exception :

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.domain.project.model.Item
```

The message is clear but I don't see how to proceed since all concrete classes are initialized in database when the app starts.
How to tell to JPA/Hibernate that all `Item` subclasses are already saved so it should use them instead.

Any help. Thanks

Comment: Post the code where you construct and save a new Menu.

Comment: @AlanHay even if your comment is really general, it helps me to find my mistake. I made my tests by adding a new Item in my items list, I didn't load them from database so their id where `null` ! ..... My mistake [-_-]

Comment: Usually will get this issue when child obj(mapping object) is null

Comment: @soorapadman exactly

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a many-to-many relationship, this will also allow more flexibility if you want to remove items from a menu but not from all menus.

Menu <--> MenuItem <--> Item

The new MenuItem entity will have primary keys for both menu and item.

[Many to Many example](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html)

Comment: My children instances (subclasses) are already persisted. So I don't want to persist them again. I just want to persist a `Menu` without cascading since they already exist.